# How to reset specific selected option in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, select2-rails

For example i have 2 records pre-selected as seen in screenshot below.

I noticed that `aria-selected="true"` for selected ones.

How can I find it by `title` and remove/reset it so it will not be part of current selected items.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select2` has link to particular `<select>` element in DOM. So, first you need to change select option, and then trigger `change` event of `select2`
For change `option` text you can like this

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="option1">Text</option>
</select>

var $select2 = $("#mySelect").select2();
$('#mySelect option[value="option1"]').text = 'Another text';
```

And then trigger `change` event for `select2`:

```
$select2.trigger("change");
```

### Remove item

```
$('#mySelect option[value="option1"]').remove();
$select2.trigger("change");
```

### Select one option

```
$select2.val("option1").trigger("change");
```

### Select multiple options

```
$select2.val(["option1", "option2"]).trigger("change");
```

### Remove one from selected

If you need remove one option from already selected, you need to get selected options, remove one, and set new options to select2.

```
var sel = $select2.val(); // array
sel.splice(sel.indexOf("option1"), 1);
$select2.val(sel).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$('#idSelect option[title="myTitle"]').first().remove();
```

Hope it helps.